# [42000][904] ORA-00904: : invalid identifier Position: 128 when creating table

Tags: oracle

These two tables (Payment_Method and Orders) cannot be created. I will get invalid identifier error.

```
create table Payment_Method(
                               id integer primary key,
                               fullname varchar(20),
                               comment varchar(30)
);

CREATE table Orders(
                       order_id integer,
                       status varchar(20),
                       comment varchar(50),
                       customer_id integer,
                       delivery_address varchar(30),
                       store_id integer,
                       primary key (order_id),
                       foreign key (customer_id) references Customer(customer_id)
);
```

But for this customer table, I can create firstly.

```
create table Customer(
                         customer_id integer primary key,
                         fullname varchar(20),
                         password varchar(20),
                         phone varchar(20),
                         email varchar(30),
                         address varchar(30),
                         VIP_Level varchar(20),
                         customer_since date,
                         customer_order_id integer
);
```

Table Payment_Method is an independent table which has no referenced one, but it still cannot be created. And I can create these tables in MySQL workbench, but in Oracle, I cannot do that. It's so annoying.

Comment: Comment is reserved word go for `comments`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `COMMENT` as a column name as it is an oracle reserved keyword.

```
CREATE TABLE PAYMENT_METHOD (
    ID         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    FULLNAME   VARCHAR(20),
    COMMENT_   VARCHAR(30) <-- change in the column name
);

CREATE TABLE ORDERS (
    ORDER_ID           INTEGER,
    STATUS             VARCHAR(20),
    COMMENT_           VARCHAR(50), <-- change in the column name
    CUSTOMER_ID        INTEGER,
    DELIVERY_ADDRESS   VARCHAR(30),
    STORE_ID           INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY ( ORDER_ID ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( CUSTOMER_ID )
        REFERENCES CUSTOMER ( CUSTOMER_ID )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`comment` is a reserved SQL keyword. Try to use another column name.

See [list of reserved SQL keywords](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621).